# Eclipse - Tomcat VM arguments does not change

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I would like to change the value of `-Dwtp.deploy` of my Tomcat VM arguments.

So I double click on my server end go to `Open launch configuration` but when I Apply and Close the value of -Dwtp.deploy don't change.

There is a default value who replace my change ?

Comment: Why change it? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: I have to change it because my project use many diferent folder and the Dwtp.deploy have to be another folder than my workspace.

Comment: What value are you changing it to?

Comment: -Dwtp.deploy contains the path of my workspace et I want to set the path of my runtime environment.

Comment: Do you have the option to serve without publishing enabled? If so, try turning it off.

Comment: I turn it off and I change ```Deploy path```, now it's work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the option to serve without publishing enabled? If so, try turning it off.